# A què se debe este error en asp mvc 4 - enviar mensaje

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

Buenos dìas, me sale el error en la línea 21, no encuentro el problema, pues se imrpime el mensaje que está enviado.

[image: error al momento de ejecutar]

```
@{
    var customerName = Request["customerName"];
    var customerEmail = Request["customerEmail"];
    var customerRequest = Request["customerRequest"];
    var errorMessage = "";
    var debuggingFlag = false;
    try
    {

        // Initialize WebMail helper
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";

        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "Edward";
        WebMail.From = "...@gmail.com";
        WebMail.Password = "password";

        WebMail.EnableSsl = true;

        // Send email
        WebMail.Send(to: "edw.0919@gmail.com",
            subject: "Help request from - " + customerName,
            body: customerRequest
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        <text>@ex</text>
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes el servidor de smtp mal configurado. Contactate con el administrador del servidor y verifica que tienes las credenciales correctas.

Comment: pero es de gmail, sabes alguna alternativa?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y publica el codigo de envio de email .

Comment: Por favor no incluyas imágenes con el mensaje, en su lugar coloca el texto como tal

Comment: @edwardericksonfiestasflores puede que sea pro el puerto. Revisa esta [página](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854).

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro pero creo que Gmail aún bloquea las conexiones smtp para envíos masivos de correo. Básicamente es problema de Gmail, no deberías de enviar correos desde una cuenta normal. podrías utilizar servicios como https://www.mailgun.com/ https://mailchimp.com/ etc.

Comment: como dice @MauricioAriasOlave es el puerto, puedes revisar este enlace  https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=ese